# how do i count table rows and show it input form in spring boot?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot with thymeleaf. i am new with spring boot. I have a table named Menu, with column(id, menuname, url)
I have done CRUD operations for this table. Now I want to count the number of rows and display it in input form.
For example if I have 5 rows, I want to make my dropdown box to be with options 1 up to number of rows that is 1,2,3,4,5
if my rows is 7, then thymeleaf dropdown list will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

**in my  menuservice class I try this**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)  
public long getCountOfEntities() {
    long count = menuRepository.count();
    return count;
}
```

I just stuck here... please help me.

Comment: So, does the method above work? do you get the number of records in `count` variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending **CrudRepository** or **JpaRepository**, you can use *count()* method available. Else you can write custom query like below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: It looks like he is already using it `menuRepository.count();`

Comment: yes correct, unless he specifies the repository code, its difficult to guess. I am assuming he is either extending CrudRepository or JpaRepository. It should return the count in the variable which he is already using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate options for your select in HTML.
Try using th:each and #numbers.sequence(from, to)

```
<select>
    <option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, count)}" th:value="${i}" th:text="${i}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also [thymeleaf tutorials](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html) should be able to help you.